# Further information on the reduction of cubic equations to a system of two conic sections

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, cubics, roots-of-cubics

This question follows on from one I have previously asked, [How to separate cubic equations into two conic sections: Deep dive into Omar Khayyam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585401/how-to-separate-cubic-equations-into-two-conic-sections-deep-dive-into-omar-kha) and I now would like some further advice on some particular forms of cubic equations.

The first case is an equation of the form: $ x^3 = ax^2 + bx + c $ being reduced to two hyperbolas.

The second case is an equation of the form: $ x^3 + bx = ax^2 +c $ being reduced to a hyperbola and a circle.

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide

Edit:

Equation of the form $x^3 + ax^2 + bx = c$ should apparently break down into a hyperbola and **semicircle** (meaning that its centre lies along either the x or y axis exactly) can the second example be extended to this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several different solutions are possible. I managed to find Khayyam's paper online and here are his solutions. Of course he used a purely geometrical language and gave his solution as a construction, followed by a proof that this was indeed right. I'll reverse his reasoning, as you seem to prefer, and use a more familiar language.

First case: $x^3=ax^2+bx+c$.

We can rewrite this equation as:
$$
x^2(x-a)=b\left(x+{c\over b}\right)
$$
and multiply both sides by $(x+{c/ b})$, obtaining:
$$
\tag{1}
x^2(x-a)\left(x+{c\over b}\right)=b\left(x+{c\over b}\right)^2.
$$
If we set now:
$$
\tag{2}
y^2=(x-a)\left(x+{c\over b}\right),
$$
which is the equation of a rectangular hyperbola,
we can rewrite $(1)$ as:
$$
x^2y^2=\left(\sqrt{b}x+{c\over \sqrt{b}}\right)^2.
$$
But this is the square of
$$
\tag{3}
xy=\sqrt{b}x+{c\over \sqrt{b}},
$$
which is the equation of another rectangular hyperbola.
Our equation is then equivalent to the system formed by $(2)$ and $(3)$.

---

Second case: $x^3+bx=ax^2+c$.

Set:
$$
b=h^2,\quad c=sh^2
$$
and rewrite the equation as
$$
h^2(x-s)=x^2(a-x).
$$
Now multiply both sides by $(x-s)$ (this will introduce the spurious solution $x=s$, which must be discarded) to obtain:
$$
\tag{4}
h^2(x-s)^2=x^2(a-x)(x-s).
$$
If we set now:
$$
\tag{5}
(a-x)(x-s)=(h-y)^2,
$$
which is the equation of a circle, and substitute into $(4)$, we get
$$
h^2(x-s)^2=x^2(h-y)^2.
$$
But this is the square of:
$$
\tag{6}
h(x-s)=x(h-y),
$$
which is the equation of a rectangular hyperbola.
The solution of the original equation can then be obtained as the abscissa of the second intersection between circle $(5)$ and hyperbola $(6)$, their first intersection being point $(s,h)$.

EDIT.

For the case $x^3+ax^2+bx=c$ Khayyam makes the same construction as in the case $x^3+bx=ax^2+c$ outlined above. Just make the substitution $a\to-a$ in the above explanation to find the corresponding hyperbola and circle.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Any chance you could link the paper you found here too?

Comment: @Bountifull It's a book with the translation of Khayyam's treatise in Russian... I'll see if I can trace back the URL.

Comment: Here it is: https://vk.com/wall-55397733_916?lang=en

Comment: Thank you! My dissertation adviser can read Russian so this will be really useful!

Comment: @Bountifull I also added the second case.

Comment: I've been trying to work this out on my own for about a week now and can say I absolutely would never have figured this out, thank you so much!

Comment: I have edited the question to extend the second case if you could provide any help that would be great!

Comment: @Bountifull Yes, it is as you thought, see my edit.